# How to get data only for certain hours over past 30 days

Tags: mysql, timestamp, between

I have a few programs and their timing is like below :

P1 : 5PM to 8pm
P2 : 8PM to 1AM
P3 : 2AM to 4AM

Lets suppose for P2 I have to get the last 30 days of records.  I was using this query.

```
select * from {table} 
WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '01-09-2013 8pm' AND '30-09-2013 1am'
```

However that query returns records that are outside of the time of P2 because i am using `between`.

I want to get 30 days records but it should also limit it to only those between 8pm to 1am daily only.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The Simplest approach would be :

```
select * from {table} 
WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '01-09-2013' AND '30-09-2013'
AND DATE_FORMAT(timestamp,'%H') in ("20","21","22","23","00")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from {table} 
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp) BETWEEN '01-09-2013' AND '01-10-2013' 
AND (FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp,'%H')>=20 OR FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp,'%H')<=1)
```

Comment: I've assumed (maybe incorrectly) that you want the results on a monthly basis. In which case you could even have the query return results for 'this month' `...WHERE date_format(timestamp, '%Y-%m') = date_format(now(), '%Y-%m') AND ...`

Comment: I am using strtotime format in timestamp field and my query was  "Select * from table WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '1378051260' AND '1380488340' " but it search all day timinig and you know i only need the results for let suppose 8pm to 1am for 30 days or whatever date selected by the user.

Comment: Make sure mysql interprets your timestamp as a date (or your dates as a timestamp `UNIX_TIMESTAMP('01-09-2013')`). I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Ok Thanks alot , let me test this.

Comment: Hi , I have tried to use this query but its not working giving empty result. please check am i doing something wrong with this .
<code>SELECT * from radio_interactions WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '1378051260' AND '1380488340' AND (DATE_FORMAT('1378051260','%H')>=20 or DATE_FORMAT('1380488340','%H')<=1)</code>